# Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create the following application with ruby on rails programming: application that displays a page of thumbnail images with each thumbnail linked to a corresponding full-sized image. When the user clicks on the thumbnail, the application will display the images. I downloaded sqlite3 as a database. I tried to do different procedures. I used scaffolding and migrations but I cannot make it to work. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the images from? Is the user uploading them or are your targeting a pre-existing gallery? When you say is doesn't work, what do you mean exactly? Are there any error messages you can share with us?

Comment: I think you'll find this community is very willing to help, but probably not to do the entire job for you.

Comment: You're going to have to break your question down into specifics; this is far to general. Can you add more information about what you've tried, where you are, and what you're stuck on? As it stands, the only answer we can give is "Read a tutorial on Rails".

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip gem shall do the job. The railscasts is bit old and you may refer to github for various updates.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip